# Chania port to Chania city

Tags: public-transport, ferries, greece

How can I go to the Chania city from the Chania port by bus?

I come from Athens by boat.

By the way, how much is the ticket?

Comment: On foot? By bike? By taxi? By public transport? Hitchiking? Other?

Comment: Are you arriving at the port in Chania or in Souda?

Comment: There are two different ports for Chania?

Comment: @kaiser Yes. Chania and Souda. Both have ferries departing from Piraeus. Which company are you sailing with?

Comment: @JoErNanO Anek.

Answer (score 6):

With Anek you are likely to arrive in Souda rather than in the Chania port. According to [the official Municipality of Chania website](http://www.chania.gr/), which links to [this Chania Tourism website in English](http://www.chaniatourism.com/useful-information.html), there are buses running between Souda and the main market square in Chania, departing every 20-odd minutes. To date these seem to be operated by [Chania Bus](http://chaniabus.gr/en/#main). For more information here is a quote from the Chania Tourism website:

> #### Buses
>
> Chania City Bus (routes from Chania to all places of the city, Akrotiri, Souda, port, and the popular beaches of the municipality) - Address: 1866 Square, Chania, Tel.: +30 28210 27044, e - mail: chaniabus@gmail.com, url: www.chaniabus.gr